# Find code on back end used by the front end

Tags: sql-server-2012

We have a front end system that links to our SQL Server 2012. For most things I use the back end system, however there are some things I still use the front end for.

The reason for this is because I have not found how to do these on the back end yet. One of the front end task I use gives errors all the time and I was wanting to try to find the code it is using on the back end so I could find the problem. I have no idea what code it uses though is there a way for me to find out.

I do not know if it uses stored procedures or triggers or something else I may not have heard of yet.

The front end job is just a mass enroll into a table. Which I assume would be done using something like a bulk insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the *SQL Server Profiler* (to be found in SSMS menu "Extras").

Let it pause, clear all output and navigate your application just before the "last click".

Then start the profiler and push the process you want to monitor.

After this you'll find a list of all jobs SQL Server was running.

Comment: I am not finding sql server profiler or extras in any of the menus of SSMS 2012. Can you post a screenshot of where to look?

Comment: Sorry, my SSMS is German, therefore a screenshot would not help probably. Might be, that you did not install the Profiler... [Read this](http://superuser.com/questions/414662/why-dont-i-have-sql-profiler-on-sql-server-management-studio)

Comment: Ok I will talk with IT and see if that is something they are willing to install for me.

Comment: @ChadPortman, did you read the link I posted? Did you find the `.exe` in the filesystem? If not, you'll have to install it. It's really useful!

Comment: I did read it and did not find the .exe that is why I am going to talk to IT and see if they are willing to install for me